# Extract sound from video

Tags: c++, multimedia

I'm currently doing my Multimedia assignment where I have to create a new video using one video as a foreground and another as a background. OpenCV allows me to do just that: extracting images from each frame in video, processing them and putting the results back into a video format. However, OpenCV is only a computer vision library. Is there a library that allows me to do the same for sound? I'd like to extract sound (music, actually) from a video I'm using and put it into the final video.

Comment: Are you writing an application to do this or do you just need a program to do it for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use libavcodec library used in [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Try Tuna Audio Extracter (http://github.com/tuna74/TunaAudioExtracter). You can use the extracter part from that program.